# df -h and df -kh?

Tags: linux, disk-usage

What’s the difference between `df -h` and `df -kh`?

I am trying both these commands in my terminal, however I don’t see any visible difference so wanted to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is effectively no difference.

The `-h` option to `df` selects "human readable" output, meaning that the sizes of things will be scaled to appropriate amounts to give nice small readable values, such as 2.1G, or 806M.

The `-k` option does something similar, but scales the sizes to kilobytes only, so you'll get e.g. 2165680 and 824550 instead of 2.1G and 806M.

Since these options are conflicting with each other (you can't both have the sizes in kilobytes and in "human readable" format), the last of option specified will "win".  The combination of these options that you use, `-kh` (which is the same as `-k -h`), means that you'll get the effect of using only `-h`. There is therefore no difference between `df -h` and `df -kh`.

Compare this behavior with conflicting options to other utilities, such as the `-C`, the `-1` ("minus one"), and the `-l` ("minus ell") option to `ls`, and what happens if you use all in one order or the other.

Answer (score -1):

`df -kh` is probably a bit slower that `df -h`. You probably can't measure it, but it will take a bit longer to parse its arguments.

For those that know how to program in languages where the variables are mutable (C, python, bash, ...), then it is something like this.

```
set mode to k
set mode to h
do everything else
```

vs

```
set mode to h
do everything else
```

By the time the program gets to the `do everything else`, the mode is set to h.